# How do I make this SVG and Buttons not overlap each when they scale?

Tags: css, svg, flexbox, responsive

I am having some trouble keeping this svg, and flexbox buttons from scaling over each other when scaling down. I want to use flexbox so that I can control the buttons and SVG overlay over this hero shot at all time.

Is there a better way to accomplish this, or am I screwed lol?
Any recommendations would be appreciated.

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .ob-hero-container {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .herobtn-container {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60%;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .herosvg-container {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: -20%;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .herobtn-wrapper {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    .herobtn1 {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        /*margin: .1em;*/
        text-align: center;
    }
    /* Tablet */
    
    @media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn-wrapper {
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    /* Mobile */
    
    @media (max-width:30em) {
        .herobtn-wrapper {
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="ob-hero-container">
    <!-- IMAGE BACKGROUND --><img src="https://s21.postimg.org/jp1vyijrb/sample.jpg" width="100%">
    <!-- END IMAGE BACKGROUND -->
    <div class="herosvg-container"><img src="http://svgshare.com/i/23M.svg" width="100%"></div>
    <div class="herobtn-container">
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">SHOP WOMEN'S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">SHOP MEN'S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">SHOP KIDS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">WATCH VIDEO</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't allow for the `.herosvg-container` holding the *svg text* to be able to grow below the starting point for the buttons.

This change in the `.herosvg-container` rule will make them not overlap

```
  top: 0;               /*  changed  */
  height: 60%;          /*  changed  */
  /*  bottom: 0;            removed  */
```

Stack snippet

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .ob-hero-container {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .herobtn-container {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60%;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .herosvg-container {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;               /*  changed  */
        height: 60%;          /*  changed  */
        /*  bottom: 0;            removed  */
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .herobtn-wrapper {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    .herobtn1 {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        /*margin: .1em;*/
        text-align: center;
    }
    /* Tablet */
    
    @media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn-wrapper {
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:50em) {
        .herobtn-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    /* Mobile */
    
    @media (max-width:30em) {
        .herobtn-wrapper {
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="ob-hero-container">
    <!-- IMAGE BACKGROUND --><img src="https://s21.postimg.org/jp1vyijrb/sample.jpg" width="100%">
    <!-- END IMAGE BACKGROUND -->
    <div class="herosvg-container"><img src="http://svgshare.com/i/23M.svg" width="100%"></div>
    <div class="herobtn-container">
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">SHOP WOMEN'S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">SHOP MEN'S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">SHOP KIDS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
            <div class="herobtn1">WATCH VIDEO</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both the `svg` container and `button` container together. This ensures that they won't overlap.

Example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ob-hero-container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.herosvg-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em; /* styling for demo */
}

.herobtn-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.herobtn-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.herobtn1 {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  /*margin: .1em;*/
  text-align: center;
}


/* Tablet */

@media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em) {
  .herobtn-wrapper {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:50em) {
  .herobtn-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Mobile */

@media (max-width:30em) {
  .herobtn-wrapper {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ob-hero-container">
  <!-- VIDEO BACKGROUND -->
  <!--
    <video autoplay="" loop="" preload="auto" width="100%">
        <source src="http://media.rackroomshoes.com/uploads/awhitten/obsw/bts-video.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2" />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
-->
  <!-- END VIDEO BACKGROUND -->
  <!-- IMAGE BACKGROUND --><img src="https://s21.postimg.org/jp1vyijrb/sample.jpg" width="100%">
  <!-- END IMAGE BACKGROUND -->
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="herosvg-container"><img src="http://svgshare.com/i/23M.svg" width="100%"></div>
    <div class="herobtn-container">
      <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
        <div class="herobtn1">SHOP WOMEN'S</div>
      </div>
      <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
        <div class="herobtn1">SHOP MEN'S</div>
      </div>
      <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
        <div class="herobtn1">SHOP KIDS</div>
      </div>
      <div class="herobtn-wrapper">
        <div class="herobtn1">WATCH VIDEO</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /overlay -->
</div>
```

Comment: I would but I need the buttons to drop out of the video for mobile. Plus I would like to be able to float the SVG & Flexbox buttons differently sometimes. So they would both need to be separate controls I feel like.

Comment: You can still hide the button container using media queries?

Comment: take a look at what I'm trying to accomplish in the end results.